# Input time format - NSDate formatter issue

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a time format like this :- 2014-09-10T16:04:44

I am using the code below to convert it to `NSString` but I am getting `NULL` value for that

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateformatter dateFromString:obj.strResultDate];
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong ? I think it must be input time format but I dont know what.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"\n"
      "theDate: |%@| \n"
      "theTime: |%@| \n"
      , theDate, theTime);
```

Comment: In this code "now" is only getting alloc and init and then from that it is getting converted to NSString . It won't give us anything

Answer (score 0):

For converting this string into date, do as follows:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-09-10T16:04:44";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSDate *convertedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", convertedDate);
```

This may be helpful!